# Given $x, y \in \mathbb{C}^n$, then $|x^* y|^2 \leq \alpha$ is equivalent to $x^* y \leq \sqrt{\alpha} \exp\{i \theta \} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

> Given $x, y \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$,
>
> Is $|x^* y|^2 \leq \alpha \Longleftrightarrow x^* y \leq \sqrt{\alpha} \exp\{i \theta \} $ for some arbitrary $\theta$, where $()^*$ denotes complex conjugate transpose? True or False?

---

This is true. Right? Sorry for confirming simple question.

Since $|x^* y|^2 \leq \alpha \Longleftrightarrow |x^* y| \leq \sqrt{\alpha} \Longleftrightarrow x^* y \leq \sqrt{\alpha} \exp\{i \theta \} $.

Comment: $x^* y \leq \sqrt{\alpha} \exp\{i \theta \}$ does not make sense as $(\Bbb C,<)$ is not well-defined.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, oh yes. I see. Thank you